# Azure Worker Role machine from the customized image

Tags: c#, azure

I know how to create a Worker Role in Visual Studio and publish the machine to Windows Azure.
I can install applications and setup the machine in the role OnStart() method.

This all creates the machine from the default Azure image.
I can also create a customized Windows image and save it in my storage account.

Is it possible to deploy a Worker Role machine using this customized image instead of using the default image?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to use customized image for a worker role. Your only other alternative would be to use IaaS Virtual Machines.